# Is there an "authoritative" source for ephemeris data?

Tags: astronomy, specific-reference

I find some variation in the values reported for ephemeris by the various sources I have access to. For example for 2012-11-27T03:31:55 UTC I get solar declination values of [-21.1828°](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sun%20declination%20at%203:31:55%20AM%20GMT%202012-11-27), [-21.18296°](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AstronomicalData.html), [-21.1814°](http://nancocad.com/sundec/sundec.htm), [-21.1834°](http://store.simulationcurriculum.com/products/pro-plus), [-21.1906°](http://www.stellarium.org) and (again)  [-21.1814°](http://www.celnav.de/longterm.htm). Are the differences among these values meaningful? Is there an "authoritative" source (ideally online) for ephemeris data?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you gotten similar inconsistencies with point sources? The Sun might be special. Also, a quick glance tells me several of these sites give $\pm 1$ arcsecond (0.0003 degrees) as the precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most authoritative solar system ephemeris system is the JPL Horizons system. There is a [web interface](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) that will let you perform computations and extract solar system data from the JPL development ephemerides, the international standard.

Comment: Which, of course, gives yet another value: 21.1523°.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha is a black box that I wouldn't trust compared to Horizons. As I said, it is THE definitive standard and assumes the user knows what is needed. What is your intended purpose? See the book Fundamental Ephemeris Computations (1999, Willmann-Bell) for details on the internals of JPL ephemerides.

Comment: Agreed. That's what started me wondering. I was using Wolfram (Alpha and *Mathematica*'s `AstronomicalData`) and was getting weird results. Do you know if there is a web-based API that uses their algorithms? Something I can call from code as a substitute for `AstronomicalData`. (I can check the docs, but if you know off hand that would be great.)

Comment: My purpose is just basic study, so I don't need especially precise ephemeris (e.g., I'm not aiming a research telescope). One thing I'm trying to do "rediscover" some basic astronomical patterns and properties (e.g. the equation of time) using the datasets such as Wolfram's `AstronomicalData`, but I keep running up against small discrepancies that I can't explain, and wonder of they're from inaccuracies in the data. (That matters because the alternative may be instructive, e.g. revealing something like precession or $\Delta T$.)

Comment: Again I say that JPL's Horizons is your best bet. I have no knowledge of what Mathematica or Wolfram|Alpha use internally. Are you computing apparent coordinates? Mean coordinates? Topocentric coordinates? Are you accounting for precession?

Comment: After reading your last comment, Mathematica's model is probably adequate for what you're doing.

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure what these systems are giving me. I'm assuming they're astrometric geocentric coordinates, accounting for precession. Yes I expect Mathematica is good enough (and that in most cases, when I see small deviations from what I expect, its probably noise, or even floating point errors).

Comment: I think I may still get your book, load the C code, and call that from Mathematica (if only to do a comparison).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Even if you were aiming a research telescope, these inconsistencies aren't necessarily a problem. Even pro telescopes have backlash and star positions are shifted due to the atmosphere anyway. Thus we generally point telescopes using guide cameras and precise offsets to nearby bright objects, rather than absolute coordinates.

Comment: A further note: the Wolfram numbers may not be so bad after all. The JPL number in my first comment was astrometric, but the "airless apparent" value is 21.18286°; quite close the the Wolfram values.

Comment: And while [this site](http://www.celnav.de/longterm.htm) agrees with Wolfram values for the Moon, JPL gives values that are almost a degree off. So I'm confused, again.

Comment: That means that Wolfram uses the same truncated implementation of the VSOP analytical theory that Meeus uses which, at best, only approximate (albeit well) the JPL ephemerides, which are generated from numerical integrations and least squares fits to observational data. For Moon, did you account for parallax?

Comment: I'm [a bit confused](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45354/2540) about what JPL means by "UT".

Comment: Are there any Python libraries that provide programmatic access to the JPL ephemeris data?

Comment: [AstroPy](http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/rowen/AstroPy.html) claims to provide access to JPL ephemeris data files but I've never tried it.